# How do I return the response from an ajax call to store in a variable?

Tags: ajax, variables, return

I would like to store a response result from an ajax call. This is because the ajax is the main API call used by several functions to extract information from an API.

I call callAPI function more than 8 times in my app.
Of course, I can duplicate the function callAPI 8 times to properly get information but this is not cool way to code.

```
var result = callAPI("GET",url,'');
$('#status').val(result.success);
$('#output').val(result);
```

```
function callAPI(method_input, url_input, body_input){
    var urli = url_input;
    var datai = body_input;
    var method = method_input;

    $.ajax({
        url: urli,
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("some header","some value");
        },
        type: method,
        data: datai,
    })
    .done(function(data,status) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data,status) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    });
  }
```

I tried to store the return value using 
var result = ajax(value);
but the result is empty

is there any way to store return value of a function to a variable?

EDIT
I Solved this problem by using callback function like below

```
function callbackResult(result){
$('#status').val(result.success);
$('#output').val(result);
}
```

```
function callAPI(method_input, url_input, body_input, callback){
    var urli = url_input;
    var datai = body_input;
    var method = method_input;

    $.ajax({
        url: urli,
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("some header","some value");
        },
        type: method,
        data: datai,
    })
    .done(function(data,status) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
        callback(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data,status) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(data);
        return JSON.stringify(data);
        callback(data);
    });
  }
```

This was my first function to use a callback function and now I know what the callback function is.

Thank you guys all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

You need `'async': false`, so:

```js
var result = $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/users",
    'async': false,
    type: 'GET'
})
.done(function(data,status) {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function(data,status) {
    console.log("error");
});


console.log("result: " + result.responseText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, current version is working like you mentioned but i need to call the callAPI 8 times and i need to put same code 8 times with little bit different result set which is in ".done(function(_){". So i would like to remove the code that replicated 8 times. To do that i need the result of the callAPI. this is my question.

Comment: Edited, you can check it now @brian17nz

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

1. Instead of `JSON.stringify()` I think you want to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the JSON string that is probably been returned by your API.
2. You can use the `$.ajax` option `dataType` to automatically parse the JSON string into an object.
3. [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a promise which can be chained to add as many callbacks as needed.

A more elegant solution would be to return the promise from your function and chain your callbacks. Ex:

```
    function callAPI(method_input, url_input, body_input) {
      var urli = url_input;
      var datai = body_input;
      var method = method_input;

      return $.ajax({
          url: urli,
          // Automatically parses JSON response
          dataType: 'json', 
          beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("some header", "some value");
          },
          type: method,
          data: datai,
        })
        .done(function(data, status) {
          console.log("success");
          console.log(data);      
        })
        .fail(function(data, status) {
          console.log("error");
          console.log(data);      
        });
    }

    callAPI('GET', '').then(function(result){
      // Do something with my API result
    });
```

If you plan on making all request at once, with this solution you can consider aggregating all the request into a single promise with [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Ex:

```
    $.when(
      callAPI('GET', ''),
      callAPI('GET', 'second'),
      callAPI('GET', 'third')
    ).then(function(firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult){
      // Do stuff with the result of all three requests
    });
```